# Form+Ajax doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Form+Ajax -> Results on exact DIV
3 hours, 53 minutes ago|LINK

Hi,

I need to visualize my partialView (results after a form submission) in a DIV.

I have the following files:

**View Man_por.cshtml**

```
...

<div class="col-md4" id="divTabPortfolios">

enter code here@{Html.RenderAction("Load_portfoliosPartial","Management_portfolios");}

<div>

<div class="col-md4" id="divTabPortfolio">

<div>

...
```

**View Load_portfolios_partial**

```
<script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

....

...

@using ( @ Html.BeginForm() )

{

....

...

<button type="submit" class=".." value="Open"/>

}
```

**Script MyScript.js**

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#divTabPortfolio').html(result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

When it shows the result it open entire page and not a partial view  (_layout.cshtml+Page) etc.. and it doesn't update the specified DIV.

How could i solve it?

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML in addition to or rather than the ASP code? Assuming the issue isn't server-side that code is irrelevant, and kind of meaningless to people like me who don't code in ASP.

Comment: I can't copy and paste from server. What part do you want to see?

Comment: Press Ctrl+U while viewing the page. That's what we want. Make sure you only get the html that is relevant and format it correctly.

Comment: How is `$.fn.valid` defined?

Comment: Why aren't you using `@using (Ajax.beginForm())` instead of `@using (Html.beginForm()`? MVC supports Ajax forms out-of-the-box. You then provide the action, controller and selector (for the panel to update)... Job done.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@using (Ajax.beginForm())` instead of `@using (Html.beginForm()`.

MVC supports Ajax forms out-of-the-box.

You then provide the action, controller and selector (`UpdateTargetId` is set to the id of the panel to update) like this:

```
<div id="divTabPortfolio">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SomeAction", "YourController", new { id = optionalParameters }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "divTabPortfolio" }))
    { 
    }
</div>
```

No need for your own jQuery/Ajax for this sort of basic Ajax post-backs in MVC/Razor.

So long as your action method returns a `PartialView` you don't need to do anything else.

*As suggested, if you could post more of the page it would help provide specifics*

Comment: Sorry, but I don'understand the following reasons: 
1) I need to update another div-section respect to the source section where I will call the method. (in your example above I see you update the same div)
2) What are the advantages to use Ajax.beginForm respect to Html.beginForm? (I believe the problem is something about the rendering) 3) I can't copy the source because It is on the remote server where I have not the grants. :(

Comment: In that way How can i add an animation during the call to server on that div?

Comment: 1) You can update any div. It does not have to be the one with the form in it. It can be just one button/link in a form to trigger panel update. 2) `Ajax.BeginForm` does all the Ajax async/update plumbing you were doing manually for you. `Html.BeginForm` just creates a standard postback form. 3) It is difficult to give good help without a better example. You might want to try mocking up a dummy page/project that does what you want and post those pieces.

Comment: As for loading animation, `Ajax.BeginForm` has a `LoadingElementId` option that can show/hide an element containing your loading animation.

Comment: when I click on the form button to submit the data i would like I would use again the same form to submit other data but the event doesn't work the second time. How could i solve it?

Comment: The event should work every time unless you are replacing the form itself. Basically not enough information to help on this new problem.  Add a new question for it, with a cut & paste of just the relevant parts of the HTML (very hard to do this blind).